Closure of orbit of Borel subgroup $B_n$ acting on triangular matrices $T_n$.
Let $\Bbbk$ be an infinite field. Consider the set of $n\times n$ upper-triangular matrices $T_n$. Let $B_n$ be the set of invertible $n\times n$ upper-triangular matrices. Consider the following action:
$$
\begin{array}{rll}
(B_n\times B_n)\times T_n&\longrightarrow T_n \\
(b_1,b_2)\times b&\longmapsto &b_1bb_2^{-1}
\end{array}
$$
I want to find a good description of Zariski closure of orbits of diagonal matrices.
To simplify it more, we consider matrices with only 1 or 0 on its diagonal.
Acting with arbitrary matrix from $B_n$ on the left allows us to fill all columns with 1 as diagonal element. But acting both on the right and on the left doesn't allow us to get any upper-triangular matrix with zeroes at the same place as the original diagonal one.
I am mostly interested in closure and since Zariski topology is weaker, Zariski closure contains Euclidean closure. I want to show that Euclidean closure is Zariski closed set hence Euclidean closure coincide with Zariski closure.
So far, I checked that we can get any matrix with 1 zero on diagonal if it's also one in the original matrix. If we have two adjacent zeroes $a_{i,i}$ and $a_{i+1,i+1}$, than also $a_{i,i+1} = 0$. There is a requirement on rank of a submatrix other zero positions. I think this submatrix somehow defined by the zero elements on matrix's diagonal, but I can't see the precise answer. This would solve the question, since the closure will be an affine space with one equation (det of submatrix is zero)

Hint: Check that any upper-triangular matrix whose diagonal entries are pairwise distinct can be diagonalized by conjugation with an invertible upper-triangular matrix.

@Sasha that's definitely true since it's has pairwise distinct eigenvalues. Probably I can continue like this. We can multiply by diagonal matrix on one side. And get more zeroes on diagonal after we take closure. Since the initial position of zeroes on diagonal can't be changed, it describes the closure of orbit. But I can't understand how to prove that closed in standard topoly set is Zariaki closed. Because equality of some diagonal elements to zero is not enough.

You don't need "to continue", because upper-triangular matrices with distinct diagonal entries are dense is all upper-triangular matrices.
